# Google fetch failed after enabling cloudflare SSL

Tags: nginx, https, http-status-code-301, cloudflare, google-search-console

I get a certificate from Cloudflare and enable https from Cloudflare API.
then add SSL certificate to my Nginx config.

then add some page rule to redirect non-www and non-https to www and https version of my website
after that my website works fine but when I add https version of my website to google webmaster tools and try to fetch I get 301 error

I even clear all page rules and handle them in Nginx but I had no luck with webmaster tools.

can anyone help?

Comment: A 301 is a redirect error. You mentioned that you added a page rule to redirect non-www, so are you sure you are using www in Google Search Console? If you try adding the https/non-www version, a 301 would be expected.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett I add 4 version of m website to Search Console (non-www, www, HTTP and https version) but all of them redirected